# Not able to run sample chat code of quickblox application in Eclipse

Tags: quickblox

I am not able to run sample Quickblox chat code in Eclipse IDE. I am getting errors in rooms.xml file. The error is:

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'Show as Action' in package com.quickblox.sample.chat.